# wordpress - add page-sidebar from plugin

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I am looking to add a sidebar from a plugin file. There is a filter for this that can be used for pages and im looking for something similiar for side-bars. Sorry theres no attempt but i can't find a filter to try with!

Comment: not sure why anyone would vote this down, but just in case there is confusion over what is being asked, i am looking for a filter or hook which is not in the codex for get_sidebar, basically i am creating a plugin and want to store the sidebar template in the plugin rather than a theme which is not included in the package.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin for add a sidebar https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-sidebars

Comment: hi mate thanks for the help, but all this does is register the sidebars, i need a filter to change where get_sidebar looks for its templates.